# DrawString and Render graphics after custom time

Tags: java, graphics, timer, swing

I want to draw String after some second like "Boss is incoming",and after the string is disappeared i want to draw the Boss.I have the graphics and the string so my question is how to add timer for string and graphics?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have paintComponent() already set up. You just need to use [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)) and [java.util.TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#run()). Timer is a class that runs a method implemented in TimerTask after a delay. TimerTask is an abstract class that allows you to implement the method that Timer runs. The function that Timer runs is TimerTask's run().

In TimerTask's run(), you just need to add code that changes what repaint() draws.

```
//set up Timer so it runs after how many seconds you need the text to appear for.
//Then in your TimerTask implementation add code that removes the text and then renders your new image

@Override
public void run()
{
    //code that removes text
    //code that renders image
}
```

If you your paintComponent() draws based on an ArrayList of images, your run implementation could probably look like this:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    imageList.remove(yourString);
    imageList.add(theBoss);
}
```